# CPU ID using C++ - windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to get CPU Id  of my computer (windows) using c++.

I used [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get it.

It outputs information something like:

```
For InfoType 0
CPUInfo[0] = 0x5
CPUInfo[1] = 0x756e6547
CPUInfo[2] = 0x6c65746e
CPUInfo[3] = 0x49656e69

For InfoType 1
CPUInfo[0] = 0xf31
CPUInfo[1] = 0x20800
CPUInfo[2] = 0x41d
CPUInfo[3] = 0xbfebfbff

For InfoType 2
CPUInfo[0] = 0x605b5001
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x7c7040

For InfoType 3
CPUInfo[0] = 0x0
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 4
CPUInfo[0] = 0x0
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 5
CPUInfo[0] = 0x40
CPUInfo[1] = 0x40
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 80000000
CPUInfo[0] = 0x80000008
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 80000001
CPUInfo[0] = 0x0
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 80000002
CPUInfo[0] = 0x20202020
CPUInfo[1] = 0x20202020
CPUInfo[2] = 0x20202020
CPUInfo[3] = 0x20202020

For InfoType 80000003
CPUInfo[0] = 0x47202020
CPUInfo[1] = 0x69756e65
CPUInfo[2] = 0x4920656e
CPUInfo[3] = 0x6c65746e

For InfoType 80000004
CPUInfo[0] = 0x20295228
CPUInfo[1] = 0x20555043
CPUInfo[2] = 0x30382e32
CPUInfo[3] = 0x7a4847

For InfoType 80000005
CPUInfo[0] = 0x0
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 80000006
CPUInfo[0] = 0x0
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x4008040
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 80000007
CPUInfo[0] = 0x0
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0

For InfoType 80000008
CPUInfo[0] = 0x2028
CPUInfo[1] = 0x0
CPUInfo[2] = 0x0
CPUInfo[3] = 0x0
```

I could not understand among those information which is my computer's unique CPU Id.

Can anyone kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean "serial number", "who made the processor", or the "string that identifies the make and model of the processor".

**Serial number:**

Unless you have a Pentium III, you do not have a "unique ID" associated with your CPU.

Intel introduced the unique id (serial number) instruction with the P3. But after a huge uproar over privacy, they quickly disabled that feature in subsequent CPU releases.

For the record, the instruction that executed this feature in assembly:

```
mov eax, 3
cpuid
```

The processor serial number was the concatenation of eax, edx, and ecx together

You can achieve the same thing with __cpuid function by passing "3" as the second parameter. But it won't work or return a serial number unless you have a P3.

**Vendor (who made the processor)**

```
int regs[4] = {0};
char vendor[13];
__cpuid(regs, 0);              // mov eax,0; cpuid
memcpy(vendor, &regs[1], 4);   // copy EBX
memcpy(vendor+4, &regs[3], 4); // copy EDX
memcpy(vendor+8, &regs[2], 4); // copy ECX
vendor[12] = '\0';
print("My CPU is a %s\n", vendor);
```

In your case, this should print "GenuineIntel".

**Make and Model (BRAND String)**

If you want all the details of the CPUID instruction, including on how to get the make, model, and stepping of your CPU, as well as the "Brand String" such as "Intel(R) Core (TM)i7-3770 CPU @ 3.4GHZ...." you can reference the Intel manual at the link below. Scroll down the document to find the docs for CPUID.  I'm too lazy to type it up for you.

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.pdf

The __cpuid() instruction provided by the MSVC compiler maps "InfoType" to EAX before the call to the cpuid instruction. After that instruction returns, EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX get copied to the CPUInfo[4] array you passed into this function.

Comment: thanks. can I use, InfoType 0 of   __cpuid as the CPU's unique identifier

Comment: as it gives "CPU Identification String"

Comment: @duskwuff, is there any way to generate UID from those strings ? may be by using all InfoType ?

Comment: @user1838343: What part of "you do not have a unique ID" in selbie's answer was unclear?

Comment: @user1838343: You could create a "not unique at all" ID by combining the vendor, family, model and stepping fields. An ID like this would allow you to tell the difference between different types of CPUs, but would not let you tell the difference between 2 different CPUs of the same type.

Comment: You can actually get the "Brand String" with the CPUID call. The link the OP provided has the sample code to do this.

Comment: @selbie: The "brand string" is dodgy marketing crud (far less reliable), and isn't supported on old CPUs at all

Comment: Example of dodgy marketing crud: I have a "Xeon" - is it Pentium II or Haswell or something in between?

Comment: @Brendan - I think to get the entire string beyond the first 4 characters, you have to call cpuid multiple times with different values of EAX passed in.  In short, this is the same string that the "dxdiag" program that comes with Windows will show when you run in in the "Processor:" field.  The link the OP provided actually has the sample code to do this.  As for it's usefulness, that's really up the developer to decide

Comment: @selbie: Do you realise that for a lot of (non-Intel) CPUs you can set the brand string to anything you like?

Comment: @Brendan - How is that accomplished? My assumption is that the brand string is baked into the silicon. I'm willing and interested to be educated if this is not the case.  Regardless, I'm not sure what you are trying to impress upon me. All I've done is just discuss to the OP that the cpuid instruction has lots of ways to query a processor for various make/model information and to emphasize that there is no serial number.

Comment: @selbie I really need a help. I have found lots of websites and I cannot find a good solution for finding my unique cpu id. Is there any help? I use visual studio 2015. Thx a lot.

Comment: @rickyma924 - what are you really trying to do?  As I said in the answer, there is no such thing as a "unique cpu id".  Are you looking for unique ways to identify the computer?

Comment: @selbie yes i am looking for unique ways to identify the computer

Comment: @rickyma924 - easiest thing to do is call [CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568(v=vs.85).aspx) and store it in the registry.  Then read that registry key every time you need it.

Comment: So what is Unique id for each CPU ?

Answer (score 3):

The value you are looking at is a manufacturer identifier. It is the same for all Intel CPUs — it literally just says "GenuineIntel" when read in the correct order:

```
CPUInfo[1] = 0x756e6547 = 'Genu'
CPUInfo[3] = 0x49656e69 = 'ineI'
CPUInfo[2] = 0x6c65746e = 'ntel'
```

The equivalent for AMD CPUs is "AuthenticAMD".

For additional information, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D0:_Get_vendor_ID — but, in short, there is nothing particularly unique in CPUID.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). You need to use __cpuid. Then you should extract the info based on the table.

Comment: thanks. actually, that is my question. I want to know, my CPU's unique identifier. as I understood from those linked pages, InfoType 0 is the CPU's unique identifier. however, I want to confirm.

Comment: That is what they claim so I guess it is what you are looking for. Unless of course the Microsoft webpage is wrong which is highly unlikely!