# Get vendor ID in C using cpuid

Tags: c, cpuid

I just want to get my vendor ID, i.e. GenuineIntel using cpuid in C.

This is the [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx) I want to use:

```
void __cpuid(
   int cpuInfo[4],
   int function_id
);
```

This is my wrong code:

```
int main(){
  int cpuInfo[4];
__cpuid(cpuInfo, 1);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CPU ID using C++ - windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642347/cpu-id-using-c-windows) (the C++ part there is a dud).

Comment: this is for C, not c++

Comment: Look at the answers please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running on Windows, you need to add `#include <intrin.h>` to your code. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Prototipos
int LeeIDFabricante (char * CadFabricante);
//void LeeIDModelo (char * CadenaModelo);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char CadFabricante[0x20];
    char CadenaModelo[0x40];
    int Resultado;
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "Spanish" );

    Resultado = LeeIDFabricante(CadFabricante);
    CadFabricante[12]='\0';
    printf("\nLa identificacion del fabricante es: %s. El maximo valor de CPUID es %d.\n", CadFabricante, Resultado);

    //LeeIDModelo(CadenaModelo);
    //printf("\nLa cadena de modelo es: %s\n", CadenaModelo);

    printf("\nPulse tecla RETORNO para terminar\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

int LeeIDFabricante (char *CadFabricante)
{
    int p[4] = {-1};

    __cpuid(p, 0);
    memset(CadFabricante, 0, sizeof(CadFabricante));
    *((int*)CadFabricante) = p[1];
    *((int*)(CadFabricante+4)) = p[3];
    *((int*)(CadFabricante+8)) = p[2];

    return p[0];
}
```

Comment: Answers which are just code are not the most useful. Can you expand the answer please?